# How can I test my html/php/css file for all browser?

Tags: testing, browser, web

Is there a program or method I can test my website on my computer (localhost) for all browser espacially IE versions? I use IE tester generally but it's for only IE and IE7 not working at localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe has a service called browserlab which allows you to view snapshots of your site across all browsers. Take a look [here](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html)